# How to get a custom user message when clicking on Adaptive Card button with Action.submit and object return type

Tags: typescript, botframework, adaptive-cards

i'm developing a bot with MS bot framework using the typescript sdk.
I got troubles with Adaptive cards with buttons (Action.submit). I would like to be able to display a user message when a user clicks the button that is different from the actual value that is passed.

I've got an action like this:

```
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Tell me more",
        "data": {
            "type": "messageBack",
            "choice": "TELL_ME_MORE",
            "displayText": "Ok, tell me more please!"
        }
    }
]
```

What I'd like to do is having a user message when a user clicks this button that says: "Ok, tell me more please!".
But what happens is that I see a hidden message with no text when the user clicks.
If I make "data" return a string like this instead:

```
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Tell me more",
        "data": "TELL_ME_MORE"
    }
]
```

I get a user message saying "TELL_ME_MORE" when the user clicks, but i'd like to be able to specify a different text for that message, like "Ok, tell me more please!".

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Based on the [schema](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html), the `data` field for a submit action is for adding further parameters to the action that are hidden from the user. How are you using the card? Can sending the user a message based on what they submit be the next action in your dialog?

Comment: Sending the user a message as the next action works, but that would be a message the bot sends the user. What i'd like to do is to have the same behaviour as when "data" is a simple string, meaning the user clicks the button and you see a user sent message in the chat with the button assigned value

Comment: Hmm...rather than Adaptive Cards, are you perhaps looking for [suggested actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#suggest-action-using-button)? These allow you to PostBack text to the channel as a user message which the bot will interpret.